# Convert Apache2 configuration to nginx configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php, httpd, apache2

I have RHEL 6 with apache/httpd (v2.2) configured to handle two different path of WordPress:

FOO path: `/var/www/html/FOO/`

BAR path: `/var/www/html/BAR/`

We plan to move to a new machine running RHEL 7 with nginx
I need help/assist to rewrite my old PHP configuration to new nginx configuration

Here's my old Apache2 configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/FOO
    ServerName www.Example.com
    ServerAlias Example.com
    Serveralias web.Example.com
    Alias /en/ /var/www/html/BAR/
    <Directory /var/www/html/BAR>
        Options FollowSymLinks -Indexes
        AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/FOO
    ServerName web.Example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.Example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://www.Example.com$1" [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/FOO
    ServerName Example.com


    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https://www.Example.com/$1" [L]

</VirtualHost>
```

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/FOO
    ServerName www.Example.com
    <IfModule mod_info.c>
        <Location /server-info>
                SetHandler server-info
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.1
        </Location>
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.Example\.com\.* [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.Example.com$1 [L]
    Alias /en/ /var/www/html/BAR/
    <Directory /var/www/html/BAR>
</VirtualHost>
```

My attempt NGINX configuration code

```
server {
listen 80 ;
listen [::]:80 ;
server_name Example.com www.Example.com;
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

ssl_certificate /opt/digicert/bundle.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /opt/digicert/key-nopass.pem;
ssl_session_timeout 1d;
ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets off;

ssl_dhparam /opt/digicert/dhparam.pem;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;

ssl_trusted_certificate /opt/digicert/DigiCertCA.pem;

resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=10s;

root /var/www/html/FOO;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

location /BAR/ {
            root /var/www/html/BAR/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
    }
    
    location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please also show the current state of your nginx configuration where you tried it and describe what is not working.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I edit original post with my attempt Nginx configuration

Comment: @GeraldSchneider when i try to access BAR template i got response says page cannot be found

Comment: You should skip RHEL 7 and go directly to RHEL 8. RHEL 7 is too old for new projects.

Comment: Am I understand correctly that you have two WordPress instances? The first one located in the `/var/www/html/FOO` directory and accessible under `example.com/` URL and the second one located in the `/var/www/html/BAR` directory and accessible under `example.com/en/` URL? The most simple way is to move `/var/www/html/BAR` directory content to `/var/www/html/FOO/en` directory, is it an acceptable option for you? Otherwise nginx config will be much more complex.

Comment: @MichaelHampton
Thankyou for you helpful considered point

Comment: @IvanShatsky Yah its very acceptable so could you help to convert the current configuration to Nginx

Answer (score 0):

Since you said moving `/var/www/html/BAR` directory content to the `/var/www/html/FOO/en` directory is acceptable to you, do it and use the following configuration:

```
server {
    ...
    root /var/www/html/FOO;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /en/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /en/index.php?$args;
    }

    ...
```

You can leave the other locations unchanged.

This way any request starting with `/en/` would go to the second WordPress instance while all the other requests would go to the first WordPress instance.